# Why does Lexical Analyzer for a C program again generate a C program "lex.yy.c"?

Tags: c, parsing, flex-lexer, lex

I know a lex file after compilation produces lex.yy.c

Now suppose i am making a C expression parser.
why does the lex always autogenerate a C file.
What sense does it make to parse C using another C program?

Comment: GCC's C and C++ compilers are mostly written in C. Clang's C and C++ compilers are written in C++. I suspect Microsoft's C and C++ compiler is written mostly in C and C++.

Comment: It is nearly impossible to write a meaningful program entirely in yacc and lex. The bulk of your program's logic remains written in a "host" language - i.e. C or C++.

Comment: @Mat agreed. But my question here is how the lanaguage itself is made, how is it capable of writing that compiler, something must have initially compiled it and made it functional so as to be able to make a compiler.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)

Comment: You are refering to the Bootstrap (in German aka Münchhausen) Problem.

Comment: @Mat Thanks a lot. I guess that's what i was looking for.